# Repeater, Table e Updatepanel - Não Funcionando Corretamente (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu gostaria de sua ajuda com Repeater, Table e UpdatePanel juntos no ASP.NET usando c #.

O que eu preciso? Eu tenho categoria e itens (com peso) e o usuário precisa definir uma nota para aquele item. Na CodeBehinde eu soma peso com nota e eu tenho um resultado.

Qual é o meu problema? Eu posso obter um retorno corretamente (valores), mas ele está ficando fora da minha Table (que funcionam com Repeater).

Eu procurei muita solução, mas nada está funcionando. Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

Obrigado.

ASPX:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"> </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterItem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterItem_ItemDataBound" 
                            OnItemCommand="RepeaterItem_ItemCommand" 
                            onitemcreated="RepeaterItem_ItemCreated" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:14px">
                        <thead>
                        </thead>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tbody class="border border-0">
                        <tr> 
                            <td class="col-1 border border-primary"> <asp:Label  ID="LabelId" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </td>                                
                            <td class="col-2 border border-primary text-center"> <asp:Label  ID="LabelNome" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </td>
                            <td class="col-1 border border-primary text-center"> <asp:Label  ID="LabelValor" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </td>
                            <td class="col-1 border border-primary text-center"> <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control"  AutoPostBack="true" ID="textFunc" OnTextChanged="textFunc_OnTextChanged" runat="server" type="number" Text="" value="5" min="0" max="5" maxlength="1"></asp:TextBox> </td>

                   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >        
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <td > <asp:Label ID="LabelResultadoFinal" runat="server" Text="."></asp:Label></td>            
                        </ContentTemplate>
                         <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="textFunc" EventName="TextChanged"/>
             </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>     
                            <td class="col-1 border border-primary text-center"> <input  type="button" id="testButton" data-target='<%#"#accordion" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>' data-toggle="collapse" value="+"></input></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" class="hiddenRow">
                                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="accordion<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>">   
                                    <textarea class="form-control mt-2 mb-2 col-8" id="Textarea<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>" rows="3"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

C#:

```
 ToolBOX.BLL.Relatorio.RelatorioLigacaoBO relatorioSelecionado;     
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            relatorioSelecionado = new ToolBOX.BLL.Relatorio.RelatorioLigacaoBO();
             RepeaterItem.DataSource = relatorioSelecionado.ObterItensPorCategoria(1);
            RepeaterItem.DataBind();

       }

 protected void RepeaterItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            ClassAuditoriaItem Item = (ClassAuditoriaItem)e.Item.DataItem;


            Label LabelId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelId");
            Label LabelNome = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelNome");
            Label LabelValor = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelValor");
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText tx1 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)e.Item.FindControl("text1");


            LabelId.Text = Item.Id.ToString();
            LabelNome.Text = Item.Nome;
            LabelValor.Text = Item.Valor.ToString();

        }
    }

 protected void textFunc_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TextBoxNota = ((TextBox)(sender));

        RepeaterItem rp1 = ((RepeaterItem)(TextBoxNota.NamingContainer));


        Label LabelValor = (Label)rp1.FindControl("LabelValor");
        Label LabelResultadoFinal = (Label)rp1.FindControl("LabelResultadoFinal");

        LabelResultadoFinal.Text =  Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(LabelValor.Text) / 5) * Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxNota.Text));



    }
```

No final, o cálculo funciona, mas não está substituindo os campos originais. Ele adiciona novos campos na página da posição superior.

[Here what is heppening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRDei.png)

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda de todos.

Comment: Você gerou 6 colunas (`td`) na primeira linha do `tbody`, mas depois na segunda linha, faz uma coluna com `colspan="5"`, não deveria ser `colspan="6"`?

Comment: Olá, você tem razão. Corrigi isso, mas o problema continua acontecendo. Os dados são atualizados corretamente, conforme CodeBehind, mas são criados novos dados na tela. Agradeço desde já sua contribuição.